# VSTOR40 Bootstrapper Package Misssing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsto, prerequisites

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** to deploy an **Outlook Add-In** and for some reason I was not able to specify the **Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 4.0 Runtime** as a prerequisite for my add-in.

When I checked my `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` folder I found that there was no entry for it at all.I have also checked all of the other Microsoft SDK folders trying to find it.

This would be okay if I could find anywhere online to download it.

Is my only option to do a full reinstall of Visual Studio and hope it shows up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck at a dead end on this.

Comment: How are you deploying the plugin? Are you using Installshield, Wix, etc?

Comment: Missing on mine as well.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479

Comment: Deployment with ClickOnce. But the Setup.exe it produces isn't installing VSTO before the add-in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer found at,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2012/12/21/creating-a-bootstrapper-package-for-an-office-2013-vsto-add-in-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Thank you for your suggestions everyone.